# Filter res.users by email in Odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I need to check if a given email is associated to a user

```
class validate(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/cp/validate_email/<email>', auth='none', type='json',website=True)
    def validate_user(self,email,**kwargs):
        res = http.request.env['res.users'].search([('login','=',email)])
        res_validate = False if len(res) > 0  else True
        return {'validate': res_validate,}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 61: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file sql_db.py, line 237
2016-05-10 03:48:00,712 23361 ERROR inova openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
.....
ProgrammingError: el operador no existe: integer = boolean
LÍNEA 1: SELECT "parent_id" FROM "res_company" WHERE "id" IN (false)
```

Comment: After using request.env[] you must add .sudo(), thats first error, make sure that in email you are getting mail text and not other object, also convert text to unicode using decode function

Comment: Thanks!
your answer was more complete but I can't choose as the correct becourse it's a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `email.encode('utf-8')` instead of `email` here `[('login','=',email)]`  , as the email have some special character in your case.